# Can't start any linux distro from usb

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

Long story sort, I created a bootable usb of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (or Linux Mint) with rufus (tried with Unebootin and Etcher too). I start my pc, enter boot menu and choose to start from my usb on UEFI (tried not UEFI also) and my pc seems to restart but after that keeps running without any screen output. I tried to install windows 10 from the same usb (I made it bootable the same way) and I installed them just fine. I have installed Ubuntu previously on the same computer the same way.

CPU: AMD Athlon X4 750K

Motherboard: ASRock FM2A55M-DGS

graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 5700 Series

Any idea what to do?

Comment: didn't help either...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a similar thread on Super User, [Uefi Grub booting to Windows XP hangs at black screen](https://superuser.com/questions/450733/uefi-grub-booting-to-windows-xp-hangs-at-black-screen).

---

Here is my own experience of how to get the black screen working again.

I had the same issue of a black screen at startup although the settings seemed to be right (which they were not, in the end). See the deleted and closed [Windows 10: UEFI GTP boot stick shows black screen with a few tiny green dots at the top at start](https://superuser.com/questions/1609772/windows-10-uefi-gtp-boot-stick-shows-black-screen-with-a-few-tiny-green-dots-at?noredirect=1&lq=1). Finally I learnt that this seems to be a conflict of UEFI and legacy BIOS, of GPT and MBR.

Steps:

Press `F2` to reach the BIOS, switch to "UEFI-only", then restart and press `F9` (or try `F10` to `F12`) instead of `F2`, or even easier: a lot of new laptops have the NOVO button to directly enter UEFI without pressing any `F`-key.

Then, you will start in UEFI mode and only then you see the UEFI-only content. which is the only thing that can be loaded when having switched to UEFI-only mode at the time of choosing a UEFI startup.

It is that easy: if you do not use UEFI together with UEFI, but instead mix up UEFI with legacy, you get the black screen.